# Save changes to a color change using buttons

Tags: xcode, button, colors, save

Does anyone know how to save a change like that?  I have a settings view which is editing the backgrounds of buttons of a different.view.  I can't figure out how to save the color change.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to save the color change permanently, or only notify the other view of what color each button should be while the app is running?  There are a lot of different ways to accomplish both.